# Find $L_1$ and $L_2$ (formal languages)

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

We have two languages $L_1, L_2 \subseteq \{{a, b}\}^{*}$.

According to the following formulas find $L_1$ and $L_2$:

$L_1 = \{\lambda\} \cup \{a\}.L_1 \cup \{b\}.L_2 $

$L_2 = \{\lambda\} \cup \{b\}.L_2 $

I am trying to solve this question. extra explaination would be great. Thank you in advance for your help.

Edit 1: Here's what I think so far:

About the $L_2$, I can say that $L_2$ contains the empty string and every word in $L_2$ starts with the letter {b}.

About the $L_1$, I can say that $L_1$ also contains the empty string, every word in $L_1$ starts with the letter {a} followed by whatever we had in $L_1$ or letter {b} followed by whatever we had in $L_2$.

Is the following corrct?

$L_1 = \{a, b\}^*$

$L_2 = \{b\}.\{a, b\}^*$

Comment: Hint: assume that some non-empty word is in $L_2$. What can you say about it's first letter, and the word that you get if you remove this first letter?

Comment: Please edit your question to add: Have you made any progress so far? What specifically  are you stuck on? If nothing else, what do you know about this sort of problem?

Comment: No - consider ‘ba’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $1$ be the empty word and let $+$ denote union. Your system of equation becomes
\begin{align}
L_1 &= 1 + aL_1 + bL_2 \\
L_2 &= 1 + bL_2
\end{align}
All you need to know is [Arden's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arden%27s_rule), which states that if $K$ and $L$ are languages such that $1 \notin K$, then $K^*L$ is the unique solution to the equation $X = KX + L$.

Applying Arden's rule to the second equation, one gets $L_2 = b^*1 = b^*$.
Carrying this over to the first equation, one obtains $L_1 = 1 + aL_1 + bb^* = aL_1 + b^*$, whence $L_1 = a^*b^*$ by Arden's rule.